# How to embed an Image in Mac OS Sierra Mail Application

Tags: mac, email, graphics, html

Me and a co-worker are trying to embed an image in our email signature in the default apple mail application with an url. For example we have this image https://www.kieran.pw/unnamed.jpg and want this in our signature. We do not want a file that is being sent with the email. We tried to edit the email HTML code in ~/Library/Mail/V4/MailData/Signatures but mail just either deletes it or completely ignores it even though we edited AccountsMap.plist and AllSignatures.plist with the correct data. Did apple remove that feature with version V4 because we read a tutorial about V2 and it apparently worked there.

Comment: I am afraid this is not possible anymore. You can only insert images from local/network drives and/or links. You can even connect link to an text/image. But you cannot put image into signature from a web address.

Answer (score -2):

There’s an entire new Storage Management window, located in the System Information app, that provides a suite of tools to help you free up disk space. Some aspects of the window are based on turning on or tweaking settings, like how Mail stores attachments and if iTunes should delete video files that have already been watched.

Comment: What exactly do you mean ?

Comment: @LordLiptonIT, Anushka Chakrabarti's answer really has nothing to do with your issue other then to say that there is something new in macOS compared to previous versions or OS X but IMO it doesn't directly answer or help with your issue at all.